# Overloading a spring controller method with the same request mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a session attribute : user, and I have a url that I want to be viewed by both logged in  users and publically by people not logged in as a user.

So what I want to do is this :

```
@Controller("myController")
@SessionAttributes({"user"})
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/MyPage/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getPage(@PathVariable Integer id) {
   return modelandview1;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/MyPage/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getPage(@PathVariable Integer id, @ModelAttribute User user){
  return modelandview2;
}
```

However, I have a feeling its not going to work ... suggestions very welcome.

Comment: How is user added to the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a right case for `@SessionAttributes`. This annotation is usually used to keep original instance of a form-backing object, to avoid passing irrelevant parts of its state via hidden form fields.

Your sceanrio is completely different, thus it would be better to use `HttpSession` explicitly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/MyPage/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getPage(@PathVariable Integer id, HttpSession session) {
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute(...);
    if (user != null) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also note that `@ModelAttribute` is a subject to data binding - user can change its fields by passing request parameters. You definitely don't want it in this case.

Comment: thanks, I don't understand this "@ModelAttribute is a subject to data binding - user can change its fields by passing request parameters"

Comment: @NimChimpsky: `@ModelAttribute` works the same way as when the form is submitted. Thus, malicious user can specify additional HTTP parameters to modify fields of the `User` object.

Answer (score 2):

You only need the second method, the one that takes the User agument as well. When it's called without request attributes available to populate the User model, you'll just get a User instance with all null (or all default) field values, then in the body of the method you treat each situation accordingly